# Reset global variable in php after function return

Tags: php, function

```
$a = 0;
function a(){
    global $a;
    $success = b();
    if ($success) {
      return $a;
       $a = 0;
    }
}

function b(){
    global $a;
    $a += 9;
    return true;
}
```

In function `a` if function `b` is success then i want to return `$a` and then set `$a` to 0

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a temporary variable and then set $a before returning.

```
$temp = $a;
$a = 0;
Return $temp;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think `return $a` should be `return $temp`

Comment: Yes thank you, sorry I’m on my phone. I have corrected that now for you.